# Using the LinkedIn invitation with Scribe and Android

Tags: java, android, oauth, linkedin-api, scribe

Hi I'm using Scribe to Send a LinkedIn invite, but I'm a little unsure how to use it. I've created the XML body as a string with all the neccessary values inserted but when I make the API call the invite isn't sent. My code is as follows

```
        invite.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick (View v) 
            {
                inviteXml = inviteCreator.inviteString(to, subj, body, authName, authValue);

                titleField.setText("");


                call = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox";
                request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, call);
                //request.addPayload(inviteXml);
                request.addBodyParameter("body", inviteXml);
                service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
                response = request.send();
                nameField.setText(response.getBody());
                invite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

on the line request.addPayload(inviteXml); this causes the app to crash. The line request.addBodyParameter("body", inviteXml); returns an error xml message that has a status of 400 with an error code 0 and tht message "Couldn't parse mailbox-item document: error:Unexpected end of file after null"

Am I going about this the wrong way or have I missed something inportant? I've read the LinkedIn documentation but it doesn't seem to say how to add the xml message to the appi call.

Thanks for any help
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to specify Content-Lenght and Content-Type ?

Something like this:

`request.addHeader("Content-Length", Integer.toString(inviteXml.length()));` `request.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");`

`request.addPayload(inviteXml);`

Comment: ,I tried that but still getting the same error response returned, but it is no longer crashing on 'request.addPayload(inviteXml)' could you explain "Content-Length" and "Content-Type" are they generic headers for oAuth? would the work with something like 'request.addBody("Content-Length", Integer.toString(inviteXml.length()));'